# Paging with SQL Server offset command and front end

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

I have my paging figured out in the back end I am using the following code:

```
public ActionResult GetStockTakeAllWithPagging(int id,int StartNumber , int EndNumber)
{
    List<StockTakeAllItems> result = database.GetStockTakeAllWithPagging(id,StartNumber,EndNumber);
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I am using this SQL query and it works as should returns the right amount of rows.

```
select * 
from #StockTakeItems sti
order  by StocktakeID
offset @StartingRowNumber rows  
fetch next @EndingRowNumber -1 rows only
```

My question is on the front end I have he count of the items which is 5000 odd I was going to do a for a loop as follows But I am only wanting the for loop to hit the web service every thousand records so say if had 7041 records even though it would be easy to work out 7000 how would I work out to grab the last 41 ?

```
public async void DownloadStockCount (long warehouseId)
{
   int count= await restServices.GetStockTakeAllCountForWarehouse(warehouseId);
   var realm = Realm.GetInstance();

   List<StockTakeAllItems> results = new List<StockTakeAllItems>();

   for (int i=0;  i < count; i++)
   {
        results= await  restServices.GetStockTakeAllWithPagging(warehouseId, 1,  i);
  }

  await DisplayAlert("Test", $"Count of items for stock count {count.ToString()}", "OK");
}
```

It's here I want to send 1 - 1000, 1000, 2000 and so on until all records are fetched. Bear in mind I am using a web api which is filtering the results correctly i just need to no how to skip to the end of the recordset.

Answer (score 0):

To do that, your **GetStockTakeAllWithPagging** method should return more than just a list of **StockTakeAllItems**. You'll have to include pagination info as well, such as the number of total items in the data source. Knowing your page size (e.g. 1000) and **totalCount**, you can calculate the number of pages with this formula:

```
    const double PAGE_SIZE = 1000D;
    int pageCount = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(totalCount/PAGE_SIZE));
```

Now, if you want the last n (e.g. 41) items, you start at the last page, which is **pageCount**. Your code has to be changed to this:

```
public async Task DownloadStockCount (long warehouseId)
{
    double count = await restServices.GetStockTakeAllCountForWarehouse(warehouseId);
    int pageCount = Math.Ceiling(count / 1000);
    var realm = Realm.GetInstance();

    List<StockTakeAllItems> results = new List<StockTakeAllItems>();
    // just to make the intend of the code more concise
    int startNumber = pageCount;
    int endNumber = pageCount;
    results = await restServices.GetStockTakeAllWithPagging(warehouseId, startNumber, endNumber);

    await DisplayAlert("Test", $"Count of items for stock count {count.ToString()}", "OK");
}
``
```

Comment: Hi thanks I no that aleady as I have the count hee being returned     double count = await restServices.GetStockTakeAllCountForWarehouse(warehouseId);